# Nesting glue function in custom function

Tags: r, function, r-glue

I want to create a custom log function, that would get used in other functions. I am having issues with the custom function where arguments don't seem to flow through to the inner log function. My custom log function is inspired by the logger package but I am planning to expand this usage a bit further (so logger doesn't quite meet my needs)

```
log_fc <- function(type = c("INFO", "ERROR"), ...) {
  
  print(
    glue::glue("[{type} {Sys.time()}] ", ...)
  )
  
}
```

Next I am planning to use `log_fc` in various other custom functions, one example:

```
test_fc <- function(forecast) {

  log_fc(type = "INFO", "{forecast} is here")
  
  #print(forecast)
}
```

If I test this, I get the following error:

```
> test_fc(forecast = "d")
 Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
object 'forecast' not found
```

I am not sure why argument forecast is not being picked up by the inner test_fc function. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `.envir` argument:

```r
log_fc <- function(type = c("INFO", "ERROR"), ...) {
  env <- new.env(parent=parent.frame())
  assign("type",type,env)
  print(
    glue::glue("[{type} {Sys.time()}] ", ...,.envir = env)
  )
}


  
test_fc <- function(forecast) {
    
    log_fc(type = "INFO", "{forecast} is here")
    
}

  
test_fc("My forecast")
#> [INFO 2022-12-18 12:44:11] My forecast is here
```

Comment: That's really nice, but it ignores the `type` specification, and prints the message twice.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: see my edit : assigned `type` to `env`

Comment: That's dangerous:  it modifies `test_fc` locals.  I'd do `  env <- new.env(parent = parent.frame()); env$type <- type`.

Comment: @user2554330, thanks for your comment, updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things going on.

First, the name `forecast` is never passed to `log_fc`.  The `paste` solution never needs the name, it just needs the value, so it still works.  You'd need something like

```
log_fc(type = "INFO", "{forecast} is here", forecast = forecast)
```

to get the name into `log_fc`.

The second issue is more complicated.  It's a design decision in many tidyverse functions.  They want to be able to have code like `f(x = 3, y = x + 1)` where the `x` in the second argument gets the value that was bound to it in the first argument.

Standard R evaluation rules would not do that; they would look for `x` in the environment where `f` was called, so `f(y = x + 1, x = 3)` would bind the same values in the function as putting the arguments in the other order.

The tidyverse implementation of this non-standard evaluation messes up R's internal handling of `...`.  The workaround (described here:  https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/231) is to tell `glue()` to evaluate the arguments in a particular location.  You need to change your log function to fix this.

One possible change is shown below.  I think @Waldi's change is actually better, but I'll leave this one to show a different approach.

```r
log_fc <- function(type = c("INFO", "ERROR"), ...) {
  # Get all the arguments from ...
  args <- list(...)
  
  # The unnamed ones are messages, the named ones are substitutions
  named <- which(names(args) != "")
  
  # Put the named ones in their own environment
  e <- list2env(args[named])
  
  # Evaluate the substitutions in the new env
  print(
    glue::glue("[{type} {Sys.time()}] ", ..., .envir = e)
  )
}

test_fc <- function(forecast) {
  
  log_fc(type = "INFO", "{forecast} is here", forecast = forecast)

  }


test_fc(forecast = "d")
#> [INFO 2022-12-18 06:25:29] d is here
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: user2554330 thank you, I have gone with @Waldi 's answer but your comment has given me plenty of insight

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that when your `test_fc` function connects to the `log_fc` function, the `forecats` variable wouldn't be able to be found, because it's not a global function; thus, you can't access it from the other function.

The way to fix this is by defining a global variable:

```
log_fc <- function(type = c("INFO", "ERROR"), ...) {
  
  print(
    glue::glue("[{type} {Sys.time()}] ", ...)
  )
  
}

test_fc <- function(forecast) {

  forecast <<- forecast
  log_fc(type = "INFO", "{forecast} is here")
 
}

print(test_fc(forecast = "d"))
```

Output:

```
d is here
```

Comment: That does seem to work when you define a global variable, but could I please know why with paste (instead of glue) we don't need a global variable? i.e. 

```
log_fc_print <- function(type = c("INFO", "ERROR"), ...) {
  
  print(
    paste("[", type, Sys.time(), "]", ...)
  )
  
}

test_fc_print <- function(forecast) {
  
  log_fc_print(type = "INFO", paste(forecast, "is here"))
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `glue` you could use another `glue::glue` in `test_fc` to accomplish the pass-through, such as:

```
log_fc <- function(type = c("INFO", "ERROR"), ...) {
  print(
    glue::glue("[{type} {Sys.time()}] ", ...)
  )
}

test_fc <- function(forecast) {
  log_fc(type = "INFO", glue::glue("{forecast} is here"))
}
```

which yields

```
> test_fc('arctic blast')
[INFO 2022-12-21 15:56:18] arctic blast is here
>
```